# Color text in datatable by a given vector shiny

Tags: r, colors, shiny, cell, dt

I want to color the text of a cell in my datatable using a given vecor of values, 
I know how to change the color acording to the value inside the cell but no the cel what i want.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The library DT is what you need. http://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a vector that contains the data of wich columns must change the color.

```
) %>%
    formatStyle(
      gcolor,
      color = styleInterval(c(50), c('black', 'black')),
      backgroundColor = styleInterval(0, c('#E3F6CE', '#E3F6CE'))
    )%>%
     formatStyle(
      ycolor,
      color = styleInterval(c(50), c('black', 'black')),
      backgroundColor = styleInterval(0, c('khaki', 'khaki'))
    )%>%
     formatStyle(
      rcolor,
      color = styleInterval(c(50), c('black', 'black')),
      backgroundColor = styleInterval(0, c('#F5A9A9', '#F5A9A9'))
    ))
```